# How to exec into a spring native image?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, graalvm-native-image

I created the image following this:  
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-native-intro

I started it via `docker run image-name`

now I want to exec into it using `docker exec -it containername bash(or sh , /bin/sh)`
all fails with:

```
    OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: 
    exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown

 (or with $PATH not found)
```

running `docker inspect image-name` shows that

> "Cmd": null,

Comment: Fail how? Do you see an error?

Comment: @Paolo  sorry,edited my post

Comment: Show us the Dockerfile

Comment: I don't have , it was fully built by spring's graalvm plugin

Comment: It seems like your image didn't build correctly. `docker inspect` should return a JSON object or something like `[] \ Error: No such object: image-name`. I'd start at the top and work my way through the tutorial again, double-check spelling, etc.

Comment: @randy
It indeed returns the json,  I just quoted the relevant part 'cmd'

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately, that doesn't really say much. The image we produce for a production service has the same, but works fine.
Rereading the issue, try using `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh` rather than whatever "`bash(or sh , /bin/sh)`" was meant to be. I have a "random" mysql container that I can start and `docker exec -it /bin/bash` then `echo $SHELL` and it reports `/bin/bash`. Obviously, not your image, but just confirming that that _should_ work.

Comment: while inspecting *cmd* is not the only detail. The *Entrypoint* shown in my case to */cnb/process/web*.

Answer (score 1):

No answer yet, but as I was struggling it might save some people some time as well.

You cannot exec a shell within the image created that way as it is based on a distroless ubuntu.

As of Spring Boot 3.0.x, the base image is this one : https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bionic-tiny-stack

You have the info when you do `docker inspect` with the following line :

```
"io.buildpacks.stack.homepage": "https://github.com/paketo-buildpacks/bionic-tiny-stack",
```

If you want to change that, you have to change the base image used to build the native image.

In your `pom.xml` in the `<build><plugins>` section :

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:full</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Note the change from `builder:tiny` to `builder:full`.

And then the `docker exec` will run fine.

`docker exec -it <your_container> /bin/bash`